# Bootstrap breakpoint not triggering on ONE machine

Tags: windows, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I have a Bootstrap navbar that has a breakpoint of 767px.

One particular tester, using Google Chrome does not get the navbar breaking when amending the screen width using Developer Tools. Same Chrome version as everyone else (54.xxxx) who gets the correct behaviour. Instead, it breaks at 691px

Obviously this is a machine setting rather than Google Chrome. What could the setting be (Windows 7)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour was due to the zoom ratio on Chrome. The user had it set to 90%